# Very small images appear blurred in web pages after zooming (now webkit only)

Tags: image, browser, base64

I have very small demo images that I generate in Javascript, encode in `base64`, and display in a web page.
How can we explain and prevent the fact that this image appears blurred when enlarged?

Here is an example of a 3x2 pixels image that I enlarged to 100px:

```
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,Qk1OAAAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAAgAAAAMAAAABABgAAAAAABgAAAATCwAAEwsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8A/wAAAAD/AAAAAP8AAAAA/wD/AAAA" width="100">
```

EDIT: The proper wording for this is interpolation of course. Thanks to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Image-rendering) I found a perfect fix for FF: `style="image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges;"`. The question remains open for webkit.

Non working attempts:

```
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
image-rendering: pixelated;
```

Best but not perfect:

```
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
```

EDIT2: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5118058116939776

Answer (score 1):

Because the source is only two pixels wide, each source pixel appears 50 pixels wide. The browser tries to interpolate between the pixels given, resulting in a blurred appearance.

Comment: Interpolate was a good hint, thanks. I upvote even if you didn't give me a fix.